# PHP shorter way for IF condition

Tags: php, if-statement

Is there a shorter way to write the following IF condition in PHP?
Thanks

```
if ( ($ext != 'jpg') OR ($ext != 'png') OR ($ext !='jpeg') OR ($ext != 'gif') )
            {
                $error = 'Image type not allowed.';

            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

e.g.

```
if (!in_array($ext, array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'gif')){
  $error = 'Image type not allowed.';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (!in_array($ext, array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif')) )
    $error = 'Image type not allowed.';
```

or

```
if(!preg_match('/^(jpe?g|png|gif)$/',$ext))
    $error = 'Image type not allowed.';
```

Answer (score 1):

if (!in_array($ext, array('jpg','jpeg','gif))
{
$error = 'Image type not allowed.';
}

Answer (score 0):

All answers above are correct, but for the sake of something different:

```
$error = (!in_array($ext, array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif'))) ? 'Image type not allowed.' : '';
```

Comment: this isn't actually semantically equivalent - `isset($error)` will be different after this